# Expression Engine Path variable issue with Multisite

Tags: path, expressionengine

I have this site which uses multisite manager for minisites.

The issue i am having is that my minisites are in subfolder of the main site and when i use

```
{path='minisite/group'}
```

it creates a path like this

```
/index.php/minisite/group
```

when in fact i need the following

```
/minisite/index.php/group
```

is there a to make it aware of the baseurl for the minisite being in a subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this would be to remove "index.php" from your URLs. This is a common task in ExpressionEngine development. There's a great how-to on removing "index.php" from your ExpressionEngine sites [here](http://kevinthompson.info/blog/completely-remove-index-php-from-expressionengine-urls/). I've also used the following code in my .htaccess file to remove the "index.php":

```
# If you can't access the control panel at the folder level (ie "http://site.com/system/"), uncomment the following line.
# DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1
```

After removing "index.php" from your URLs, you should be able to use {path="} without error. Let us know if this isn't the case.

Comment: cheers i'll give it a go. i didn't try the particular one you are giving me now but i'll let you know if it's right.

wouldn't removing the index.php make subgroups clash with potential minisites? although i've name those so that they won't clash.

Comment: I don't _think_ subgroups will clash with potential minisites, but I can't guarantee that they won't. Best of luck!

Comment: it's worked a charm, i noticed in general configuration that you have to put /minisite as the index page and put the .htaccess in the /minisite sub folder.